# TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR to get orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) `TYPE_ORIENTATION` should not be used anymore but instead `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` and `getRotationMatrix()` in conjunction with `remapCoordinateSystem()` and `getOrientation()` to compute

I am taking the output of `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` which is a 4D Quaternion and converting it to Euler. Is this correct? If it is then why and how should I use `getRotationMatrix()` in conjunction with `remapCoordinateSystem()` and `getOrientation()`?